# How to disable the CoreCLR Tiered Compilation?

Tags: jit, coreclr

Tiered compilation can mess up the assembler output when doing optimization work. Is there any way to disable it to get the high-quality output assembler without the need to pre-heat the method?

Comment: Couldn't find how to do it, so I am answering it myself.

Comment: Please also write a question and create an answer to it when posting a Q&A pair. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours. Thank you for investing the time to add the knowledge you couldn't find!

Comment: Should it make sense to modify it now?

Comment: probably.. as you have seen, there are other options as well, like fixing it for a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to your project should work too.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>          
      <TieredCompilation>false</TieredCompilation>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable the tiered compilation for the CoreCLR for all projects set the relevant environment variable:

```
set COMPlus_TieredCompilation=0
```

You can set it up for the machine to disable it altogether or set it immediately before you call your executable to have it disabled temporarily.